# Is there anything like earlyoom for CPU usage?

Tags: swap

There are programs like earlyoom that when RAM and swap are almost full, they kill processes. I was just wondering if there’s something like that that kills processes when the CPU is overloaded.

Comment: You can check this Q/A: https://serverfault.com/questions/97541/kill-process-with-high-cpu-usage-after-x-time