# Prevent any one process from hogging CPU/RAM causing lock-up?

Tags: systemd, freeze, cgroups, cpu-usage

It's happened to me a few times that something has started to consume a crazy amount of CPU or RAM, making the system unusable to me even to kill it; so my only option is a (physical) reboot.

A couple of the culprits I've specifically limited as a result, using systemd's 'resource control'/cgroups.

Is there something I can do that's more general, preventing *any* single process from being too much of a hog? Or perhaps limiting the entire session, so that I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F#</kbd> to a new one to recover?

Comment: Someone posted this: "On Linux systems there are two shell utility available to set the I/O and CPU Scheduling for a application or script. 
The utility are named nice and ionice." I have not used them and do not know details. See man pages for more info.

Comment: `earlyoom` and alike might help.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks that's exactly the sort of thing I was hoping for! Do you know of anything similar for CPU?

Comment: Ah that's already been asked here (no answers atm) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371858/is-there-anything-like-earlyoom-for-cpu-usage

Comment: Unless you're running 10 tasks simultaneously on each of your CPU cores, I see no use for such an utility since Linux can multitask quite effectively but you could use cgroups for that, e.g. https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-cgroups-to-control-cpu-usage/  https://www.google.com/search?q=cgroups+CPU+limit

Comment: The most recent issue I had was with CPU rather than an OOM - it wasn't 10 tasks simultaneously on each core, it was just vim, I (accidentally) opened a (not small) binary, and it (or a plugin/s) went crazy, maxing each core and system totally unresponsive. If that happens, I'd be perfectly happy killing the highest CPU user, since my alternative is killing everything by forcing a reboot. I mentioned cgroups in OP, but I don't know a way to do that generically, I don't know that it'll be vim next time, and it's not feasible to do it explicitly for each program.

Comment: That's weird. I've never seen a PC stall due to a CPU use contention but then I now have an eight-core CPU with 16 threads.

Comment: It's not so much that it *stalled* as was busy and unresponsive, but showed no signs of completing. Kubernetes can reserve resources for the system, and uses either cgroupfs or systemd (interchangeably), so perhaps I could get somewhere looking at how it does that.